# directive's isolate scope function is not being called from my template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

I have a directive and unfortunately, the call I'm making from the template isn't going through to the template itself. To test this I actually made another scope variable called helloWorld and attempted to use that string and display it. This string wasn't displayed either. This disconnect from the scope and the directive's template is very confusing. Code below:

```
angular.module('application.directives').directive('addSegment', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      addmodel:'=',
      seg:'='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.helloWorld = "hello      Worldly things";
      scope.selectedsegment = function(s,add){
        console.log("inside selectedsegment");
                if(typeof add.selectedSegments === "undefined" ){
                  add.selectedSegments = [];
                }
                var ind = add.selectedSegments.indexOf(s.id);
                if(ind === -1){
                    add.selectedSegments.push(s.id);
                }else{
                   add.selectedSegments.splice(ind,1);
               }
           }
    },
    template: "<div ng-repeat='segment in seg|filter:{status:0}'><label>{{helloWorld}}</label><input type='checkbox' ng-click='selectedsegment(segment,addmodel)'/></div>"
  };
});
```

call from my html:

```
<add-segment addModel='addGainCreator' seg='segments'></add-segment>
```

Any help on fixing this issue would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Show how are you using the directive and data in the `seg` array? It's quite possible that the `ng-repeat` actually filters out everything

Comment: So I'm creating ngmodels of objects that are composed of three things. title, description, and array of segments. the segments array is being displayed as objected for users to click. upon clicking a textbox, the array is populated with the clicked segment's checkbox's id or deleted if it already existed. What's interesting is that my segments data will display, but nothing in the scope that I newly set is being processed.

Comment: where's the `ng-model` at...none of those in code shown? Sounds like you are breaking the golden rule of not using objects in `ng-model`. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: sorry, it's not an ng-model. I've used it as a ng-model in other places in my html such as a text box and such. here I just pass it in as a variable and use it as a variable as we can see from the template.

Comment: still guessing issue is related to using primitives and not objects. No way to troubleshoot without us being able to reproduce problem which is why the demo was requested

Comment: I don't know how to create a demo, but I can give you more information? the objects I'm passing in are:
`$scope.addProduct = {selectedSegments:[]};
$scope.segments = [];
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this odd bug some time ago.

It's because of a combination of:

1. `replace: true`,
2. isolate scope, and
3. a root element of the template having element transclusion (due to `ng-repeat`, but same would be true with `ng-if`).

The bug is that `replace` "breaks" the scope that was created on that element.

Anyway, the fix is to add a root element wrapping the `ng-repeat`ed element in the template:

```
template: '<div><div ng-repeat="segment in seg">...</div></div>'
```

**OR** remove the `replace: true`, since it is anyway deprecated.

Comment: that's such a weird bug, thanks for helping with that. I would have never figured it out.